# Resolve dependencies not available in Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, url-routing, karma-jasmine

I am currently setting up a resolve property on one of my routes in my Angular app. I am using ngRoute. Also, I inject a service called `Session` into my resolve function.

My route looks like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/projects', {
  templateUrl: 'views/projects/index.html',
  controller: 'ProjectsCtrl',
  resolve: {
    beforeAction: function (Session) { // <-- here's the injection
      // this logs an object in the browser,
      // but in my test it logs as undefined
      console.log('Session', Session);
    }
  }
});
```

In my browser, this logs `Session, Object {}` to my console, as expected.

However, when I run my tests, the same line prints `Session, undefined` to my console.

My test looks like this:

```
beforeEach(module('visibilityApp'));

var route;

describe('/projects', function () {
  beforeEach(inject(function ($route) {
    route = $route;
  }));

  it('checks if the user is logged in', function () {
    // Here I just invoke the function that's assigned to the
    // route's resolve property, but Session then seems
    // to be undefined.
    route.routes['/projects'].resolve.beforeAction();

    // then more of the test...
  });
});
```

I've already found out that it doesn't really matter what I inject into the resolve function. If I inject `$location` and log that, it's the same spiel: it works in my browser, but is undefined when I run it as a test.

My tests on Jasmine and Karma. The app was generated with Yeoman.

Why are the resolve dependencies undefined in my test? Is there some additional setup my tests need?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was one of those "I need to step away from it for an hour and come back to it" situations. It turns out that I have to inject the Session service myself if I invoke the resolve function manually.

So instead of

```
route.routes['/projects'].resolve.beforeAction();
```

I need to pass in the Session

```
route.routes['/projects'].resolve.beforeAction(Session);
```

Otherwise, the Session parameter of obviously going to be undefined. To do that, I injected the Session service into my test as such:

```
beforeEach(module('visibilityApp'));

var route,
    Session;

describe('/projects', function () {
  beforeEach(inject(function ($route, _Session_) {
    route = $route;
    Session = _Session_;
  }));

  it('checks if the user is logged in', function () {
    route.routes['/projects'].resolve.beforeAction(Session);

    // then more of the test...
  });
});
```